# Correcting an answerer

Tags: discussion

Recently, [in this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/695909/283721) an op stated in the comments section an opinion about a meta package which I believe the be simply wrong.  Is there a good way to correct that, without starting a flame war?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just disagree in one comment and let them flame.  Don't argue.  They'll tire out, and someone will flag the comments for deletion.